# Purchasing an ebook reader

Tags: hardware, devices

I want to purchase an ebook reader that is compatible with Ubuntu and can read .pdf format. Can anyone suggest a good one? I want an ebook reader not a tablet.

Comment: On askubuntu.com?  Really?

Comment: I think he may have meant "Purchasing an e-book reader *that is compatible with Ubuntu*", which would be a good question to ask here. The question may have just been phrased poorly.

Answer (score 3):

Of the most popular ones, the **Kindle 1**, **Kindle 2** and **Kindle DX** are supported by [**Calibre** [image: install calibre]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/calibre). There is also a nice [introduction to managing the Kindle with calibre](http://helpforlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/manage-kindle-from-ubuntu.html). Calibre also converts, so you're not even restricted to pdf.

**Supported devices** via the [Calibre FAQ](http://calibre-ebook.com/user_manual/faq.html):

> - SONY PRS line
> - Barnes & Noble Nook
> - Cybook Gen 3/Opus
> - Amazon Kindle line
> - Entourage Edge
> - Longshine ShineBook
> - Ectaco Jetbook
> - BeBook/BeBook Mini
> - Irex Illiad/DR1000
> - Foxit eSlick
> - PocketBook 360
> - Italica, eClicto,
> - Iriver Story
> - Airis dBook, Hanvon
> - N515, Binatone Readme
> - Teclast K3,
> - SpringDesign Alex
> - Kobo Reader
> - [...]
>
> In addition, using the Save to disk
>   function you can use it with any ebook
>   reader that exports itself as a USB
>   disk.

I can't say which one is the *best*, obviously, but the Kindle series are extremely well regarded by the reviewers - minding jrgifford's comment about the Fee for 
*Personal Document Service*. You'd also have to consider availability; this will narrow the list down to just a few, of which you should be able to chose your favourite quite easily.

Consider this an incomplete list of devices that will very probably work well with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are some ebook readers that support .pdf. You can install **[Gutenpy](http://gutenpy.sourceforge.net/)** or **[FBReader](http://www.fbreader.org/)**.

Answer (score 1):

I own the Kindle DX and I'm very happy with it. I wouldn't go for anything that has a smaller display.

[Here is a list of ereaders on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_readers)

I think that Barnes & Noble's Nook display doesn't use an electronic ink display.